# postgresql trigger function add if statement that compares old column value with a default value on update

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, string-constant

I want to create a trigger function in sql that would prevent update on a column in a table if the column value was not equal to "default_id". For example, if I update a row where `some_id` equals to "default_id", it would succeed. However, if I update a row `some_id` column that has a value that isn't equal to "default_id", it would throw an exception.

```
CREATE FUNCTION not_allow_update_column_some_id() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
    IF NEW.some_id <> OLD.some_id AND OLD.some_id <> "default_id" THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'some_id is not allowed to be updated unless it was equal to default value';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER not_allow_update_column_some_id
    BEFORE UPDATE ON some_table FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE not_allow_update_column_some_id();
```

The above code doesn't seem to work as the compare seems to think "default_id" is a column instead of a value.

Comment: You are using double quotes which makes it an identifier string. Use single quotes.

Comment: ah ops! thank you so much @AdrianKlaver